# "While read line" command is not taking all the lines from the input file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am using the below code.

```
while read line
do
  word_1=`echo $line | cut -d"[" -f1`
  word_2=`echo $line | cut -d"[" -f2`
  echo "$word_1|$word_2"
done < Input_file
```

my input file has 1000 lines, but the above code processing only few lines. And not getting any errors while running the command.

Comment: What line endings are in your file? Try `cat -vet Input_file| more`

Comment: Try `wc -l Input_file` to see how many lines `wc` can find.

Comment: the `bash -x yourscriptname` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, we need more info. However, you're doing too much work. A simpler version:

```
while IFS='[' read -r word1 word2 rest_of_line
do
  echo "$word_1|$word_2"
done < Input_file
```